# Selecting columns from joined tables in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with Laravel when trying to get a specific data from my DB.

Before I can explain my situation, here is a bit of context with an example of my DB structure.

Table `attribute`: id, name, ...
Table `attribute_value`: id, value, attribute_id, parent_id, ...

`attribute_value.attribute_id` is a reference to `attribute.id`. `attribute_value.parent_id` is a reference to `attribute_value.id`.

I need to get, for each `attribute`, it's parent `attribute`. Here's an SQL query that gets me what I need:

```sql
SELECT
    attribute.id,
    attribute.name,
    attribute.custom_name,
    parent_attribute.id,
    parent_attribute.name,
    parent_attribute.custom_name
FROM
    attribute
LEFT JOIN attribute_value ON attribute_value.attribute_id = attribute.id
LEFT JOIN attribute_value as parent_attribute_value ON parent_attribute_value.id = attribute_value.parent_id
LEFT JOIN attribute as parent_attribute ON parent_attribute_value.attribute_id = parent_attribute.id
GROUP BY attribute.id
```

Which gets me this kind of result (the two last columns are from the parent's attribute):

[image]

My problem is to get this with Laravel's Eloquent ORM. I tried using a raw select:

```php
DB::select(<<<EOT
SELECT
    attribute.id,
    attribute.name,
    attribute.custom_name,
    parent_attribute.id,
    parent_attribute.name,
    parent_attribute.custom_name
FROM
    attribute
LEFT JOIN attribute_value ON attribute_value.attribute_id = attribute.id
LEFT JOIN attribute_value as parent_attribute_value ON parent_attribute_value.id = attribute_value.parent_id
LEFT JOIN attribute as parent_attribute ON parent_attribute_value.attribute_id = parent_attribute.id
GROUP BY attribute.id
EOT);
```

But this doesn't get me the columns of `parent_attribute`. I also tried creating a `hasOneThrough` relationship on the `attribute` model but I get an error message when trying to access this field:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: \'attribute' (SQL: select `attribute_value`.*, `attribute`.`name`, `attribute`.`custom_name`, `attribute`.`type`, `attribute`.`is_custom`, `attribute`.`is_activated`, IF("Direction" = attribute.name, 1, 0) AS is_hierarchical_organisation_attribute, `attribute`.`a_t_t_r_i_b_u_t_e_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `attribute_value` inner join `attribute` on `attribute`.`id` = `attribute_value`.`a_t_t_r_i_b_u_t_e_id` inner join `attribute` on attribute_value.attribute_id = attribute.id and `attribute`.`deleted_at` is null where `attribute`.`deleted_at` is null and `attribute`.`a_t_t_r_i_b_u_t_e_id` = 3 and `attribute_value`.`deleted_at` is null and `attribute`.`is_activated` = 1)"

I really don't know how I should do and I'm really surprised a simple raw query doesn't work correctly. Can anyone help me achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you inner joining in the former query, but left joining in the latter query?
One attribute can have multiple parent_attributes or just one? And viceversa, one parent attribute can have just one child or many?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mixed up my different tryings. It should be a left join because an attribute may not have a parent and I would like to get the list of attributes + their parent if any. To answer your question, an attribute can only have zero or one parent_attribute.